# Error when not passing an kwargs in wraped function

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I'm passing kwargs to a wrapped function, and when I call the function informing some kwargs, it works ok, but when I don't pass any kwargs as parameters, I receive the error
`<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)`.

Should kwargs be optional?

My functions looks like follows:

```
def group_data(df:pd.DataFrame, group:Union[list, str], cols:Union[list, str], func:Union[list, Callable]) -> DataFrame:
        
        df = df.groupby(group)[cols].agg(func)

        if callable(func):
            df.rename(f'{func.__name__}', inplace=True)
        else:
            df.columns = [x.__name__ for x in func]

        return df

def print_subplots(df:pd.DataFrame, x:str, y:Union[list, str, Callable], nrows:int, 
                   ncols:int, func:Callable, #order:Union[list, str] = None, 
                   gr_by:Union[list, str] = None, title:str = None, figsize:tuple=(15,6)
                   , **kwargs):

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols, figsize=figsize)
    fig.suptitle(title)

    for i, element in enumerate(y):
        if type(element) == list:
            df_grouped = feature.group_data(df, gr_by, element[0], element[1])
            func(
                 ax=axes[i], 
                 data=df_grouped.reset_index(), 
                 x=gr_by[0], 
                 y=element[1].__name__,
                 **kwargs
            )
        else:
            func(ax=axes[i], data=df, x=x, y=element, **kwargs)
```

When I call :

```
print_subplots(
    pricing, 
    'search_weekday', 
    ['z_score', ['z_score', np.median]], 
    nrows=1, 
    ncols=2, 
    func=sns.boxplot, 
    gr_by=['search_weekday', 'checkin'],
    figsize=(20,6),
    order=order
)
```

...the function works fine, in this case `order` is a kwarg.

But when I call:

```
print_subplots(
    pricing, 
    'search_weekday', 
    ['z_score', ['z_score', np.median]], 
    nrows=1, 
    ncols=2, 
    func=sns.lineplot, 
    gr_by=['search_weekday', 'checkin'],
    figsize=(20,6)
)
```

...causes a loop and when I stop the process I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_192586/2963703819.py in <module>
----> 1 plots.print_subplots(
      2     pricing,
      3     'search_weekday',
      4     ['z_score', ['z_score', np.median]],
      5     nrows=1,

~/Documentos/Work/2021/ota-searches/dsc-notebooks/ota_searchs/src/visualization/plots.py in print_subplots(df, x, y, nrows, ncols, func, gr_by, title, figsize, **kwargs)
     75             )
     76         else:
---> 77             func(ax=axes[i], data=df, x=x, y=element, **kwargs)

~/Documentos/Work/2021/ota-searches/dsc-notebooks/ota_searchs/ota/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/_decorators.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     44             )
     45         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 46         return f(**kwargs)
     47     return inner_f
     48 

~/Documentos/Work/2021/ota-searches/dsc-notebooks/ota_searchs/ota/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/relational.py in lineplot(x, y, hue, size, style, data, palette, hue_order, hue_norm, sizes, size_order, size_norm, dashes, markers, style_order, units, estimator, ci, n_boot, seed, sort, err_style, err_kws, legend, ax, **kwargs)
    708     p._attach(ax)
    709 
--> 710     p.plot(ax, kwargs)
    711     return ax
    712 

~/Documentos/Work/2021/ota-searches/dsc-notebooks/ota_searchs/ota/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/relational.py in plot(self, ax, kws)
    469         # Loop over the semantic subsets and add to the plot
    470         grouping_vars = "hue", "size", "style"
--> 471         for sub_vars, sub_data in self.iter_data(grouping_vars, from_comp_data=True):
    472 
    473             if self.sort:

~/Documentos/Work/2021/ota-searches/dsc-notebooks/ota_searchs/ota/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/_core.py in iter_data(self, grouping_vars, reverse, from_comp_data)
    981 
    982         if from_comp_data:
--> 983             data = self.comp_data
    984         else:
    985             data = self.plot_data

~/Documentos/Work/2021/ota-searches/dsc-notebooks/ota_searchs/ota/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/_core.py in comp_data(self)
   1055                     orig = self.plot_data[var].dropna()
   1056                 comp_col = pd.Series(index=orig.index, dtype=float, name=var)
-> 1057                 comp_col.loc[orig.index] = pd.to_numeric(axis.convert_units(orig))
   1058 
   1059                 if axis.get_scale() == "log":

~/Documentos/Work/2021/ota-searches/dsc-notebooks/ota_searchs/ota/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    717         else:
    718             key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
--> 719         indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
    720         self._has_valid_setitem_indexer(key)
    721 

~/Documentos/Work/2021/ota-searches/dsc-notebooks/ota_searchs/ota/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _get_setitem_indexer(self, key)
    664 
    665         try:
--> 666             return self._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=0, is_setter=True)
    667         except TypeError as e:
    668 

~/Documentos/Work/2021/ota-searches/dsc-notebooks/ota_searchs/ota/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _convert_to_indexer(self, key, axis, is_setter)
   1255                 return inds
   1256             else:
-> 1257                 return self._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis)[1]
   1258         else:
   1259             try:

~/Documentos/Work/2021/ota-searches/dsc-notebooks/ota_searchs/ota/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis)
   1310             keyarr = ax.reindex(keyarr)[0]
   1311         else:
-> 1312             keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = ax._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
   1313 
   1314         self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis)

~/Documentos/Work/2021/ota-searches/dsc-notebooks/ota_searchs/ota/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _reindex_non_unique(self, target)
   3865             return self[:0], np.array([], dtype=np.intp), None
   3866 
-> 3867         indexer, missing = self.get_indexer_non_unique(target)
   3868         check = indexer != -1
   3869         new_labels = self.take(indexer[check])

~/Documentos/Work/2021/ota-searches/dsc-notebooks/ota_searchs/ota/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_indexer_non_unique(self, target)
   5256         tgt_values = target._get_engine_target()
   5257 
-> 5258         indexer, missing = self._engine.get_indexer_non_unique(tgt_values)
   5259         return ensure_platform_int(indexer), ensure_platform_int(missing)
   5260 

~/Documentos/Work/2021/ota-searches/dsc-notebooks/ota_searchs/ota/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_indexer_non_unique()

<__array_function__ internals> in resize(*args, **kwargs)

~/Documentos/Work/2021/ota-searches/dsc-notebooks/ota_searchs/ota/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in resize(a, new_shape)
   1415         extra = Na - extra
   1416 
-> 1417     a = concatenate((a,) * n_copies)
   1418     if extra > 0:
   1419         a = a[:-extra]

<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: For debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including the function call and the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341).

Comment: Updated! Tell me if it's better.

Comment: Great progress, but it's still not reproducible since `plots` is undefined, among others. And I bet it's not minimal either, though I'm not super familiar with the libraries you're using.

Comment: plots is a file that contains the function, I'll remove it